# How to mount a partition from live usb

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am trying to mount my ext4 (sdc6) partition from a live usb because that's how I deleted two unused partitions left from a prior install of ubuntu, using GParted. The swap is mounted. However, I can't edit fstab, or find anywhere to click in nautilus to mount sdc6. In the terminal, I get the error: "can't find /dev/sdc6 in fstab". I'm afraid to exit the usb and update grub if that partition isn't mounted. Is there any easy way to do this, or do I have to install gksu or some other editor? Or do I need to mount it as sda6?

```
Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 3905535 3903488  1.9G  b W95 FAT32

Device     Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1            2048   29362175  29360128    14G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdc2  *     29362176   29566975    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc3        29566976  487023432 457456457 218.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc4       487024638 1250263039 763238402   364G  5 Extended
/dev/sdc5       728393728  740290559  11896832   5.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdc6       487024640  728391679 241367040 115.1G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc6 /mnt
sudo nano /mnt/etc/fstab
```

You may need to know UUID as normally the mount in fstab is or should be by UUID.

```
sudo blkid -o list
```