# Accidentally deleted all contents of /etc/grub.d

Tags: grub2, 18.04, restore

Was trying to tweak a menu entry and in an effort to get it to work I deleted all contents of `/etc/grub.d`. Is there a way I can easily restore it? This question has to be a duplicate by now so if someone can redirect me to an answer that too would be great. :)

Comment: Although technically a duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows the answer I posted below is a lot easier in your situation of only missing the `/etc/grub.d` directory and not missing all of grub.

Answer (score 0):

Boot with your Live USB / DVD.

Open **Nautilus** in root mode using:

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

Then navigate to your `/etc` directory and copy the `grub.d` directory.

While still in `nautilus` root mode navigate to your real `/etc` directory on your hard drive SSD and paste the `grub.d` directory into it.

**Note:** You may have to mount your real Ubuntu first if `nautilus` doesn't see it on the hard drive / SSD: [How to mount a partition from live usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813640/how-to-mount-a-partition-from-live-usb)

Comment: Right, so I did what you suggested, and updated grub by chrooting to where I mounted the partition that had grub installed from the live USB. It only detected Windows though, not Ubuntu.

Comment: Um... you don't use chroot. Only mount it so you can copy to it. You should still be rooted to Live USB...

Comment: Offtopic: running into another issue: “failed to get canonical path of `/cow'. The solutions given to me by looking at other stackexchange threads aren’t working. Looking into more solutions

Comment: Um "CoW" means Copy On Write (deals with dirty disk buffers or something). "COW" can also mean "Cow-Say" which is a gimmic CLI program and probably not that. Don't really know sorry.

Comment: Found nothing of use. I really don’t understand what’s going wrong, /etc/grub.d has 10_linux so there’s no reason why only the os prober should work.

Comment: Besides 10_linux there should be 05_debian, 30_osprober and a few others.

Comment: Oh there is, there’s a whole host of other things in there with number prefixes. But only os_prober seems to be functional

Comment: After you run `sudo update-grub` you can view `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and see the other modules are included in between `#` lines. ie `### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###` and `### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###`

Comment: I don't have grub.d, it's missing, I cannot copy it. grub.cfg, and device.map were also missing, but I managed to regenerate device.map only.

Comment: @Quidam If you've found a new way of solving the problem consider posting an answer to help others.

Comment: I don't have a new way, I have the same problem.