# How to get all data from persistent live usb to preserve os

Tags: lubuntu, live-usb, data-recovery, livedvd

the producer of one software that provides software for receiving amateur metrological balloons uploaded the software to linux lubuntu persistent live to make it "user frendly" (the flash drive from the laptop interferes and is slow, and after restarting the laptop everything is restored to the initial state :-( )
but I need to record it directly to the disk so that after restarting nothing is put into the initial state and it is on the disk without persistent live mod, can someone help me please, thank you very much :D Samuel

Comment: Are you SURE it's persistent? "*[A]fter restarting the laptop everything is restored to the initial state*" strongly suggests that it's NOT persistent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mount a partition from live usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813640/how-to-mount-a-partition-from-live-usb)